# Two different pings, same domain, different subdomain

Tags: redirection

So I've got two different sub domains, one is empty (i.e. http://xyz.org) and the other is www, (i.e. http://www.xyz.org).

Now, I can't find the files for the first, when I ping the domain without the sub domain it goes to a different IP address that keeps timing out. When I ping the www. subdomain, it goes to the current Wordpress site.

What could be causing this? Here's my current .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.htm|\.html)$ /contact [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

#php_flag display_errors on
#php_value error_reporting 8191
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your domain probably did not set the wildcard handler for domains in DNS or set it wrong!

There should be an A record pointing to `*.example.com` (example being your domain name, of course)

```
*.example.com.           3600     A     192.0.2.1
```

This indicates a wildcard DNS entry with a keepalive of 3600 seconds pointing to an IP.

Please consult your provider, or if there is a DNS system, change it to reflect a wildcard entry.

Comment: Most defiantly a DNS issue,